# Extract key value pair data from avro file into a rows and column form using unix command/shell script

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with following dataset.

{"table":{"string":"ABC"}   "TYPE":{"string":"U"}   "TS":{"string":"2019-08-19 12:45:12.006362"}    "C_TS":{"string":"2019-08-19 07:45:13.631000"}  "dpt":{"string":"12345"}    "ID":{"string":"123456789"} "FUC":{"string":"ABC"}  "QDSA":{"string":"0"}   "SVCD":{"string":"S"}   }

Expecting the output in below format.
output expected :

table|type|TS|C_TS|dpt|ID|FUC|QDSA|SVCD

ABC|U|2019-08-19 12:45:12.006362|2019-08-19 07:45:13.631000|12345|123456789|ABC|0|S|

Comment: Delete this question, read [ask], look at some recent questions that received upvotes for examples if that's unclear, then try again.

Comment: If you input data is a JSON document, then please post that JSON document in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

command

```
awk -F ":" '{print $3,$NF}' p.txt| sed 's/"\}*//g'| sed "s/,NAME/|/g"| sed -r "s/\s+//g"| sed '1i table|NAME'
```

output

```
table|NAME
ABC|A

ABC|A

ABC|B

ABC|A

ABC|B
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.can you share command if i have more variables like table and NAME....there is no definite no. of key value pair.

Comment: @Abhinandan It's difficult to answer a question that is not showing all information. Please update your question.

Comment: i dont want to harcode table and Name in code....because there can be more key value pair in the data.

Comment: {"table":{"string":"ABC"},"NAME":{"string":"A"},"Dummy1":{"string":"ABC"},"Dummy2":{"string":"A"},"Dummy3":{"string":"ABC"},"Dummy4":{"string":"A"}}

Comment: @Abhinandan Please consider updating your questions. Clarifications added in comments are 1) not read, 2) poorly formatted, and 3) not part of the question.  Also add the expected output given your new data.

Comment: i just updated the one row.this is how it looks like.now i am looking to transform Key into column and value in rows.

Comment: Updated the problem statement. kinldy help

Answer (score 0):

```
$ { echo 'table|NAME'; jq -r '"\(.table.string)|\(.NAME.string)"' file; }
table|NAME
ABC|A
ABC|A
ABC|B
ABC|A
ABC|B
```

This uses `jq` to parse out the data from each JSON object, creating a string for each output line that contains the table name and `NAME` string found in the object.

The header is created using a simple `echo`.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Another jq answer:

```
{ echo 'table|NAME'; <file jq -r 'map(.string)|join("|")'; }
```

which takes advantage of `map` function for combining both `table` and `NAME` object, and `join` to concatenate both object string string.

---

Based on the last OP's question update, you would need this command (requires jq version >=1.5):

```
<file jq -r 'keys_unsorted,map(.string)|join("|")'
```

Comment: Thanks it helps :)

Comment: @Abhinandan Please look at the last update

Comment: Can i do this with awk....jq installation is not allowed asthose are blocked by client

Comment: @Abhinandan awk is not the best tool to parse json data. Use a json aware tool or language (perl, python...) to perform this task.